# Difference EPECK and CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>

Tags: c++, cgal

Hopefully someone can give me some insight why if I use the
`CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>` as Kernel my program works and it crashes if I use the `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` as Kernel;

**Problem:** I let one `CGAL::polygon_2` (diamond shaped) fall on another polygon (square). As soon as the tip of the diamond shaped polygon touches the square the program crashes during the call to `do_intersect(diamond,square)` (probably with a stack overflow) if I use the `EPECK` kernel. My understanding was that this should always work since it is exact and I thought since it does not make a construction I should even be able to use `CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel`.

It seems to start looping at the blue marked bar in the image at call: `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(2, 9, CGAL_LAZY_REP, _)`.

[image: Small part of the stack trace]

**Solution:** If I replace the EPECK with `CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>` it works.

I am willing to use this as the solution, but I want to be certain that it is actually the solution and not that I get a problem further down the line. Also some understanding would be nice why the problem is there since I thought that CGAL should be able to handle this with `EPECK` even if it might be a degenerate case.

**Additional Info**:
I have build it on 3 computers, with 2 MSVC compiler versions and 2 CGAL version all with comparable results.

- MSVC: 14.10 & 14.12
- CGAL: 4.10 & 4.12
- gmp: 5.01
- boost: 1.67.0
- windows sdk: 10.0.17134 & 10.0.14393.0
- Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: "ofcourse with the correct parentheses but I can't show them in SO" yes you can. Without a [mcve] so we can reproduce the issue, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @MarcGlisse how can I type these <> parentheses than? Sadly my code is way too big to easily scale down, it was the first thing I tried but no success in reproducing it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting (see backticks in particular)